# Uncaught error after phpmyadmin installation

Tags: phpmyadmin

Running Ubuntu 20.04 with `mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.25-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`
and `PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 15:47:56) ( NTS )`

After doing a standard install of phpmyadmin with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phpmyadmin`
```

selecting apache2 and using dbconfig-common for the database installation. I receive the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCookie() on null in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:217 Stack trace: 
#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(169): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommonRaw(Array, '?') 
#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(749): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommon(Array) 
#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(330): PhpMyAdmin\Core::linkURL('https://secure....') 
#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(353): PhpMyAdmin\Core::getPHPDocLink('book.json.php') 
#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(987): PhpMyAdmin\Core::warnMissingExtension('json', true) 
#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(106): PhpMyAdmin\Core::checkExtensions() 
#6 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(27): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...') 
#7 {main} thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 217
```

I read somewheren that the `PhpMyAdmin\Core::warnMissingExtension('json', true)` error can be resolved by editing `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/json.ini` with `priority=20 extension=json.so` Afterwords this error is gone but instead i get `PhpMyAdmin\Core::warnMissingExtension('ctype', true)`:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCookie() on null in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php:217 Stack trace: 
#0 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php(169): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommonRaw(Array, '?') 
#1 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(749): PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommon(Array) 
#2 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(330): PhpMyAdmin\Core::linkURL('https://secure....') 
#3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(353): PhpMyAdmin\Core::getPHPDocLink('book.ctype.php') 
#4 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Core.php(994): PhpMyAdmin\Core::warnMissingExtension('ctype', true)
#5 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(106): PhpMyAdmin\Core::checkExtensions() 
#6 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php(27): require_once('/usr/share/phpm...') 
#7 {main} thrown in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Url.php on line 217
```

What am i missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
priority=20
extension=ctype.so
```

to /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/ctype.ini resolved the issue.